# Django - Issue with Dynamic URL Redirect using Reverse in Model

Tags: django, django-models

I am attempting to set up dynamic URL redirecting using the method outlined in my tutorial. However, it always mangles the actual URL.

For example, it should redirect to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/3/`, but rather redirected to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/products/=/products/3/`

My redirect function in models is

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
       return reverse("product-detail", args=[self.id])
```

Note: My tutorial said I should pass in `kwargs={"id": self.id}, however, that created a whole other list of issues, and other posts I've seen pass in args, instead.

My urlpattern is `path('products/<int:my_id>/', dynamic_lookup_view, name='product-detail'),`

I've been puttering around for a while trying to figure this out. Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It should work.

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("product-detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
```